# Resolved My element isnt being found while using element.FindByName

Tags: c#, .net, maui

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Grid treeGrid = TreeView.CreateTreeView(MainGrid);
    treeGrid.StyleId = "treeGrid1";
    MainGrid.Children.Add(treeGrid);
    
}
public void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MainGrid.FindByName("treeGrid1") != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("element exists");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("cant find element");
    }
    button.Text = "OK";
    //button.Text = (int.Parse(button.Text)+1).ToString();
    //TreeView.AddTreeViewEntry(, 1, "hi");
}
```

I am using this code to add a Grid layout to my MAUI app, I set the name of the element using treeGrid.StyleId, then add it as a child of MainGrid, but when I try to find it using MainGrid.FindByName, it doesnt find the element. So my questions are, why doesnt it find the element, and how can I make it so it does find it?

I tried changing MainGrid.Children.Add(treeGrid) to MainGrid.Add(treeGrid), which didnt work.

Comment: `StyleId` is not the name of the element

Comment: @Jason then how can i set the name of the element, or find it by its StyleId?

Comment: Why do you need to?  If you are creating the element in code then you should have an explicit reference to it already.

Comment: @Jason Well, when i create the element in the Mainpage() function I can't access it in the OnButtonClicked() function

Comment: of course you can.  Create a class level reference.  This is a basic C# scope issue

Comment: I totally overlooked that option, thank you